# Google Universal Analytics not working for eCommerce tracking

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, universal-analytics

I've used the previous version of analytics many times to setup ecommerce tracking, but not getting the new universal analytics version to work.

I have this so far on the receipt page (all the variables populate correctly when I run a test transaction, I just put in placeholder variables for below example), but no pixel is fired it seems for the transaction:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-########-#', 'secure.example.com');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); 
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id': '[id]',           
        'affiliation': '[storename]',  
        'revenue':'[total]',            
        'shipping':'[shipping]',        
        'tax': '[tax]'              
    });

 #foreach ($item in $order.getItems())
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '[id]',                                                                                
      'name': '[product]',
      'sku': '[sku]',
     'category': '',
     'price': '[unitprice]',
      'quantity': '[quantity]'                                                           
    });
    #end

    ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Firing a pageview first worked for me in the previous version of analytics; is this the wrong way to structure this for the Universal analytics snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code is from our test domain which you can compare and it does send the correct data to GA for sure.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');

ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('set', 'currencyCode', 'GBP');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', { 
  'id': '100000001', 
  'affiliation': '', 
  'revenue': '143.3000', 
  'shipping': '88.3000', 
  'tax': '0.0000'});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
 'id': '100000001', 
 'name': 'Blue Horizons Bracelets', 
 'sku': 'acj0006s',
 'category': 'Bracelets', 
 'price': '55.0000', 
 'quantity': '1.0000'});

ga('ecommerce:send');
//]]>
</script>
```

If you don't mind spending some bucks then the following module could do the job for you.

For Magento 1

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-google-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html

For Magento 2

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-google-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html

Answer (score 0):

So, with a regular Universal Analytics snippet in the header doing the pageview, this works in the receipt page body:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');   

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '[id]',           
    'affiliation': '[storename]',  
    'revenue':'[total]',            
    'shipping':'[shipping]',        
    'tax': '[tax]'              
});

 #foreach ($item in $order.getItems())
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '[id]',                                                                                
  'name': '[product]',
  'sku': '[sku]',
 'category': '',
 'price': '[unitprice]',
  'quantity': '[quantity]'                                                           
});
#end

ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```